# MS-Access query to DELETE * FROM multiple tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In my Access database I have 15 tables. I want to perform [DELETE * FROM table4, table7, table8, table9, table10, table11]. That does not work, but when I run the query with one table it works, it deletes all the records in that table. I would like it to work for more than one table in a single query or in a single Visual Basic module.

Maybe I don't understand SQL and maybe this has to be done with Visual Basic?

Comment: Issue one delete per table.  Or, you might even want to just drop the tables instead.

Comment: truncate is the fastest but will reset your auto incremented fields... but have to be per table

Comment: if you want to only use one sql command then create a stored procedure that contains truncation/deletion of data per table... call the stored proc in vb to execute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MS Access' stored SQL queries only allow one DML or DDL statement at a time. For iterative actions, consider running action query in a loop using application layer code such as VBA or any language that can ODBC connect to .mdb/.accdb file. Also, `DELETE` does not need asterisk in MS Access SQL.

**VBA** *(using built-in DAO CurrentDb object)*

```vb
Dim var as Variant

For Each var In Array("table4", "table7", "table8", "table9", "table10", "table11")
   CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM " & var, dbFailOnError
Next var
```

---

#### OPEN SOURCE ALTERNATIVES

**Python** *(using pyodbc module)*

```py
import pyodbc

database = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Database\\File.accdb'
constr = "Driver={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};DBQ={0};".format(database)

db = pyodbc.connect(constr)
cur = db.cursor()

for i in ["table4", "table7", "table8", "table9", "table10", "table11"]:
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM {}".format(i))
    db.commit()

cur.close()
db.close()
```

**PHP**  *(ensure pdo_odbc is uncommented in .ini file)*

```php
$database="C:\Path\To\Database\File.accdb";

try {
  $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=$database;");

  foreach(array("table4", "table7", "table8", "table9", "table10", "table11") as $tbl){
       $sql = "DELETE FROM ".$tbl;    
       $STH = $dbh->query($sql);    
  }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
  echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
  exit;
}

$dbh = null;
```

**R** *(using RDOBC package)*

```r
library(RODBC)

database <- "C:\\Path\\To\\Database\\File.accdb"
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
                                  DBQ=', database))

lapply(c("table4", "table7", "table8", "table9", "table10", "table11"),
          function(t) sqlQuery(conn, paste0("DELETE FROM ", t)))

close(conn)
```

Comment: What? No Entity Framework?  One more thing - shouldn't these deletes be done within a transaction?

Comment: Transactions can be employed. Depends on OP's needs. Open source versions can be ignored. Future readers may find it helpful.

Comment: Great! Please accept solution (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution. Alternatives here is to dispel the myth that MS Access only works with VBA.

Comment: @Parfait Could you please provide or give a link where it shows the python code which imports the files from folder to access db ( similar to `DoCmd.TransferText` in VBA)

Comment: Actually, @Greencolor. `DoCmd.TransferText` is part of MS Access object library (not VBA). In fact, Python like VBA can interface to such methods via `win32com` which is not described in this solution. See my [multiple answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a1422451%20python%20MS%20Access%20COM) on the process.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. Only problem what I got now is that I have Code in Access that is supposed to loop through the tables which contains `PB` in table name and delete them but does not work. Could please take a look [https://pastebin.com/v402Jvym]