# Delete result from LEFT JOIN from multiple tables SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I run this query,

```
SELECT Qry_StockData_Names.CodeName
FROM Qry_StockData_Names LEFT JOIN Tbl_StockData_Codes ON Qry_StockData_Names.CodeName = Tbl_StockData_Codes.CodeName
WHERE Tbl_StockData_Codes.CodeName IS NULL;
```

it returns the CodeNames that are on `Qry_StockData_Names` but not on `Tbl_StockData_Codes` (`Qry_StockData_Names` is just a select distinct off existing data). How can I use the result from this and delete it from 3 tables. For example, say the return result is

```
CodeName
ABC
DEF
```

I would like to remove from `Tbl_StockData_Daily`, `Tbl_StockData_Weekly` and `Tbl_StockData_Monthly` all the data where the CodeName's are `ABC`, `DEF`.

Comment: `DELETE ... NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)`

Comment: can you add the RDMS you are using

Comment: @nbk Microsoft Access

Answer (score 0):

IN Access you can do this

```
DELETE FROM Qry_StockData_Names AS t1
WHERE Exists (
    SELECT t2.CodeName 
    FROM StockData_Codes AS t2
    WHERE
       t2.CodeName = t1.CodeName );
```

Comment: I don't want it to delete from `Qry_StockData_Names`, I want it to delete the result of the query from the 3 different tables.

Comment: access doesn't support this feature you can run a loop in vba https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272347/5193536

Answer (score 0):

For each of the tables `Tbl_StockData_Daily`, `Tbl_StockData_Weekly` and `Tbl_StockData_Monthly` execute a `DELETE` statement, for example:

```
DELETE FROM Tbl_StockData_Daily
WHERE CodeName IN (
  SELECT Qry_StockData_Names.CodeName
  FROM Qry_StockData_Names LEFT JOIN Tbl_StockData_Codes 
  ON Qry_StockData_Names.CodeName = Tbl_StockData_Codes.CodeName
  WHERE Tbl_StockData_Codes.CodeName IS NULL
);
```

Or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM Tbl_StockData_Daily
WHERE CodeName IN (
  SELECT n.CodeName
  FROM Qry_StockData_Names AS n
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Tbl_StockData_Codes AS c
    WHERE c.CodeName = n.CodeName
  )
);
```

Comment: That query is taking a long time, it has been running for 2 mins now and the bar hasn't moved. I only get 2 results from my select query, and just manually deleting where it has those CodeName's is quicker.

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb Check another way to do it in my edited answer.

Comment: I think something is going wrong because I even made a table out of the distinct values to speed it up and (it ran in about 1 minute runtime) but it told me that there was no way to undo the deletion because there was not enough memory, even though the deletion will only end up being a few bytes....

Comment: What about instead of using my query, how could I delete the data for the CodeNames that don't exist in `Tbl_StockData_Codes` but do exist in `Tbl_StockData_Daily`

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb I don't have your data to test. If your select query executes fast then both delete statements in my answer would also be as fast, since you get only 2 rows in the results.

Comment: It executes instantly, but your query takes a long time for some reason.

Comment: Do you have any foreign keys defined in the tables?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but the Tbl_StockData_Daily has CodeName Indexed, and has Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Date. Qry_StockData_Names just runs `SELECT DISTINCT CodeName FROM Tbl_StockData_Daily`, which runs pretty fast too.

Comment: I could even just run a query in a program to obtain the data and then iterate over and delete WHERE CodeName = '' instead, but that would make it less organised. I don't understand why the query is taking AGES

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb I don't understand either. As I said I don't have your tables to test. Just make sure that all tables involved are closed and not used by any other app.